# where a dll is being referenced

Tags: c#

Is there an easy way to determine in a large solution where a dll is being referenced the solution than using FindAll

-Rod

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the dll's namespace in a `using` statement and choose "Find all references".

You could also remove the reference to the dll and find where all the errors pop up. :P

Comment: I actually find myself using that second suggestion far more often than the first.